# android how to get the tabs like in image below in my application

Tags: android, tabs

[image: Tabs]

How can i get tabs like in this image in my app?
i am using regular TabActivity, but its not looking good. I want like this. What should I do?
Thank you

Comment: I want the tab like  http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/

Comment: here in this example how can i give each tab as an activity?

Comment: You have to Add tabbar and Put TabActivity for Each Tabs.

Comment: I am not getting u. plz give me some sample example.

Comment: no, if u ll give me some sample code its better for me. can u?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5119/discussion-between-sam-k-and-jyosna)

Comment: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1 this will be helpfull to You. If you have any Query than let me know

Comment: Have u done with Your Problem

Comment: come to chat if possible

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the same tab, you just need to go through the source of 
GreenDroid project. Its available in GitHub [Here](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/tree/master/GreenDroid/src/greendroid/widget)

Another Custom Tab open source project in code.google.com. Check [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/)

Comment: I know that, but i want it in a simple way, bcz with regular TabHost its coming but with some extra space. How can i remove that?

Comment: I have answered according to your question. What you are asking in comment is different thing. You can look [here](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=remove+space+between+tab+in+android&psj=1&oq=remove+space+between+tab+in+android&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=335489l350781l1l350899l55l54l6l25l7l2l1047l16093l5-12.10.1l26l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1f17d37ba52cd79b&biw=1600&bih=797)

Comment: But how can i put an activity to each tab? Its taking only a view